# How To jQuery JavaScript conditional statement (beginner)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Apologies if this is an overly simple question, but my searches are getting me nowhere.

I have a jQuery function which produces an error on some of my pages which do not contain the `#message` input:

```
Error: jQuery("#message").val() is undefined
Line: 56
```

And my jQuery function:

```
function updateCountdown()
{
    var $left = 255 - jQuery( '#message' ).val().length;

    jQuery( '#countdown' ).text( $left + ' Characters Remaining' );
}

$( document ).ready( function()
{
    updateCountdown();

    $( '#message' ).change( updateCountdown );
    $( '#message' ).keyup( updateCountdown );
});
```

So my question is, how do I use a conditional to remove the error message from pages without the `#message` input? I believe my problem is a basic lack of knowledge of how JavaScript works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem is with your init code.. after that it'll run fine. So do:

```
$( document ).ready( function()
{
    $( '#message' ).change( updateCountdown ).keyup( updateCountdown ).keyup();
});
```

Note the use of chaining.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't bother to perform an explicit test on the jQuery object returned from the selector — let jQuery do that for you!

```
$(function() {
  $('#message').each(function() {
    var $self = $(this);
    $self.bind('change keyup', function updateCountdown() {
      $('#countdown').text((255 - $self.val().length)) + ' characters remaining');
    });
  });
});
```

If '#message' doesn't match anything, then the `.each( ... )` call won't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Improve your selector to ensure that it's actually getting an input element (so that there is a value).  Then check to see if your selector actually matched anything before working with it.  Note that the `length` of the jQuery object returned is the number of matching elements (it must be greater than 0).  Oh, and you can consistently use the `$` function as long as there aren't any conflicts with other javascript frameworks.

```
function updateCountdown() 
{
    var msg = $('input#message');
    if (msg.length > 0) { 
        var $left = 255 - msg.val().length; 

        $( '#countdown' ).text( $left + ' Characters Remaining' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check if the jQuery object contains any items. I would do it like this.

```
$( document ).ready( function()
{
    var $message = jQuery( '#message' );
    if($message.length > 0) {
        updateCountdown();

        $( '#message' ).change( updateCountdown );
        $( '#message' ).keyup( updateCountdown );
    }
});
```

Then I'd change your `updateCountdown()` function to use the `this` keyword rather than doing another jQuery lookup. jQuery sets `this` to be the DOM element the event occurred on.

```
function updateCountdown()
{
    var $left = 255 - jQuery( this ).val().length;

    jQuery( '#countdown' ).text( $left + ' Characters Remaining' );
}
```